# PHP programming help - Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between single quote and double quote string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php)

In PHP, do both `( " )` and `( ' )` have the same effect? I'm new to PHP and I've been using them interchangeably. Can I?

Comment: I'll answer this with a similar question I posted myself... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016034/php-linefeeds-n-not-working

Comment: And see also http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php

Comment: @mario this is not "also". this is **the only** place where one have to see. Unlike inadequate answers from amateurs, it is the only reliable source of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use single quoted or double quoted strings but they have some differences. Take a look at [php string type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: An excellent answer. The only answer covers WHOLE difference yet without ridiculous superstitions peddled along.

Answer (score 0):

You you can use them interchangeably, however following are differences:

- Inside double quotes, php is able to parse variables for example

  `"Hello $name"  // result: Hello [whatever stored in $name eg John]`
- Inside single quotes php is not able to parse variables:

  `'Hello $name'  // result: Hello $name`

Since php does not parse variables from single quotes, using single quotes is slightly *faster*.

**More Information:**

- http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = 'Amar';
echo "Hello, $name"; // outputs Hello, Amar
echo 'Hello, $name'; // outputs Hello, $name
```

Single quotes ( ' ) are faster by a very small margin since they don't need to scan strings for variables.

Comment: What does it mean - "scan strings for variables"? how is it done? we take a string and scan it? why can't we do it while scanning the whole program?