# Trying to print the o/p on new line in PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php

$author="Shweta";
print <<<END
this line 
is to test
END;

?>
```

Does anyone have an idea on why this does not work?

Comment: What does not work? It has a new line, but if you are looking in browser - it interprets the output as html code. Look into the source of the page - the new line is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
<?php

$author="Shweta";
echo <<<EOT
this line 
is to test
EOT;

?>
```

Comment: And the difference is ... ?

Comment: My point is that the new line should be preserved. But its not... Its showing the entire line "this line is to test" on one single line

Comment: @tjshah050291 it is preserved, do you know the difference between the plain text (`\n` - new line) and html (`<br>` for a new line)? Read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410695/new-line-n-in-php-is-not-working

Comment: well now I do.... Thank you very much for your help! And sorry, the doubt was very silly....  trying php for the first time