# str_replace with line break?

Tags: php

I'm trying to replace a regular expression with a line break. Right now I'm trying this which doesn't work:

```
$string = str_replace(';', '\n', $string);
```

I need to make sure that semi colons are exactly the same as '\n' line breaks, how can I get this done?

Comment: Just throwing it :) try changing single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Linefeeds (\n) Not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016034/php-linefeeds-n-not-working)

Comment: So much mod fail :D "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors" - seems I'm no future visitor... I like these moderations. Never seen any that wasn't wrong.

Answer (score 26):

Use double quotes, otherwise `\n` is not parsed. [Documentation](http://php.net/string)

Comment: Oh you too fast than me +1 for you

Comment: Why have two people downvoted this answer so far? At least have the decency to explain yourselves...

Comment: @Kolink: räusper. I didn't DV, however you sometimes seem to ask for the pain with such quality answers. Leave a comment, close as too localized, go on. This is not a forum website where we all have a good time and spam the swamp.

Comment: That doesn't seem fair, downvoting an answer because of the quality of the question...

Comment: it's work for me.
thanks

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

str_replace :

```
$string = str_replace(';', "\n", $string);
echo $string;
```

preg_replace :

```
$string  = 'sdasdasd;asdasd;asdasd';

$string1 = preg_replace("/;/","\n",$string);
echo nl2br($string1);
```

Comment: it will still reflect string\nstring

Comment: looks good...however i dont prefer regular expression in this case(personal flavor lol)

Answer (score 1):

`$string = str_replace(';', "\r\n", $string);`